# How to create a child array from a parrent array?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, parent-child

My app uses multiple tableViews.

It contains a RootViewController having a NSMutableArray, named mainArray with id,parent_id,title,subtitle,description.

In my SecondTableViewController, I need to create an childArray from my mainArray depending on parent_id so I can populate the tableviewcells.

I need my childArray1 to contain only id,title,subtitle for each parent_id = 1 childArray2 to contain only id,title,subtitle for each parent_id = 2 and so on.

Are there some hints for doing this ?

Comment: First, have you considered working with NSDictionnary ? It will be much simpler to handle your elements because you have the key->value format instead of just indexes like in NSArray.

Comment: I am open to any new ideas. Like i said i'm new to Xcode.

Comment: Not sure to get you. Can you edit adding how mainArray is built ? It's an array of array?

Comment: the mainArray is an array from JSON.I'll give you the link to see the output of the json_ecode http://192.ro/ibacau/json.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by using dictionaries, I guess is better

```
NSDictionary *parent = @{@"id":@(1),@"title":@"Root",@"subtitle":@"my subtitle",@"description":@"something"};
NSDictionary *child1 = @{@"id":@(2),@"title":@"Child 1",@"subtitle":@"lalalala",@"description":@"something",@"parent":parent};
NSDictionary *child2 = @{@"id":@(3),@"title":@"Child 2",@"subtitle":@"lelelele",@"description":@"something",@"parent":child1};

//so now, you can do something like
child2[@"parent"][@"id"]; // 2
child2[@"parent"][@"parent"][@"title"]; // root
```

Comment: Thanks. I used the NSPredicate method.

Answer (score 0):

Since your JSON indicates that your NSArray contains NSDictionary objects, so here is what you can do:

```
NSPredicate *parentPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
            return evaluatedObject[@"parent_id"] == 1; //set this id to different value to get children of different parent
        }];

NSArray *childArray = [parentArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:parentPredicate];
```

You can set `parent_id` to another value to get child array of those `parent_id`s.